# Trying to hide Content Parts on Content Type

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am building Content Types and adding Content Parts specific to a Client and Attorney.  All of these parts have fields and/or content pickers, etc.

I want to restrict the Client Role to see only Client Content Parts, while I just allow the Attorney Role to see any Content Parts, including it's own Attorney Content Part for a particular Content Type.  Again, these are all on the same Content Type, so Content Permissions will not work (except on the Content Type in general).

I want to hide the Attorney Content Parts when a Client is logged on.

I have tried using this:

```
public override void Displaying(ShapeDisplayingContext context)
    {
    context.ShapeMetadata.OnDisplaying(displayedContext => {
        var shape = context.Shape;

        if (context.Shape.Part.Name == "Parts_AttorneyMatterPart")
        {
            var workContext = _workContextAccessor.GetContext();
            var user = workContext.CurrentUser;
            var roles = user.As<UserRolesPart>().Roles;

            if (!roles.Contains("Spaces Attorney"))
            {
                shape = null;
            }
        }
        });
    }
```

Where I have a Content Part named "AttorneyMatterPart", and where the Attorney Role is "Spaces Attorney".

These Content Types and Parts were all created in the Orchard Admin. The only thing in my module is this class file.

But this won't hide the Content Part when the Client is logged in. I know that I have to work on the logic of what roles can see things (going to add `||` conditions for Admin, etc.). For now I am just testing this out.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT (Bounty Added)**
I am really stumped as to whether or not this is even possible. This Content Part is created through the Admin UI. Under shape tracing I can see under the "Content" zone Model > ContentItem > AttorneyMatterPart. I have tried `ShapeTableBuilder` and I have tried `OnDisplaying` and `OnDisplayed` from a `ShapeDisplayingContext`.

If someone could provide a working sample it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a content part is created through the admin dashboard, there isn't really a shape to render it, only individual shapes for inner content fields...

So, try this

```
public override void Displaying(ShapeDisplayingContext context) {
  context.ShapeMetadata.OnDisplaying(displayedContext => {
    var shape = displayedContext.Shape;

    if (shape.ContentPart != null
      && shape.ContentPart.PartDefinition.Name == "PartName") {
      var workContext = _workContextAccessor.GetContext();
      var user = workContext.CurrentUser;

      if (user == null || !user.Has<UserRolesPart>()
        || !user.As<UserRolesPart>().Roles.Contains("RoleName")) {
        displayedContext.ChildContent = new System.Web.HtmlString("");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

See my answer on OrchardPros

http://orchardpros.net/tickets/6914

Best

Answer (score 1):

Nulling the `shape` variable will just clear the local reference. Setting the following however should hide the shape:

```
displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Position = "-";
```

Also FYI it's better not to check on roles the user have but rather create a custom permission, add that to the user role and then check for the permission through

```
IAuthorizationService.TryCheckAccess()
```

Comment: I think this is not working for me because I am accessing the Content Part wrong. I created the Content Part in the Admin UI. Is this correct: `context.Shape.Part.Name == "Parts_AttorneyMatterPart"`?

Comment: You can always check with the debugger what is there, but I think you want this check for displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Type.

Comment: It's not clear how the provided answer doesn't work for you. How does it fail exactly?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I think the problem may be that I am creating the Content Part in the Admin UI. This is not a Part created from a module. I have tried "Parts_AttorneyMatterPart" and "AttorneyMatterPart" but the Part is not getting hidden using the "-" setting that was suggested. I am starting to think this is not possible.