# Orchard Content Parts that Don't Store Information in the Database

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to create a content part in Orchard that will perform a request to a web server and display the results of the request. The problem I'm running into is that my part requires no user input and thus I have left the part and part record classes empty. I have a Migrations.cs file that adds a description to the part and makes it attachable as well as creates a content item with the part attached to it. When I go to create a new instance of my content type it tries writing to the database and fails. How do you create a content part in orchard that doesn't try to save to the database? Thank you.

The actual error I receive is:
null id in Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentTypeRecord

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't need to create new table since there are many parts which don't have any in Orchard. Try to remove **MyCustomPartRecord.cs** and change **MyCustomPart.cs**

```
public class MyCustomPart : ContentPart<MyCustomPartRecord>
```

to

```
public class MyCustomPart : ContentPart
```

Then just add driver and view and you should be good without extra tables ... In theory :D

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Would this apply to parts you created in the UI. Meaning, if I am allowing fields to save into Infoset, but I need to deal with hiding the part or creating alternates, can I still do this so that the system picks up the part so that I can actually hide the part programmatically or create alternates? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423023/trying-to-hide-content-parts-on-content-type

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem is even when your part ins't actually saving anything in the database you still need to include a table for the part so it can store the id. I just added the following to my Migrations.cs file and it fixed the problem.

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("MyCustomPartRecord",
    table => table
        .ContentPartRecord()
);
```

Comment: See @xeevis's answer - if you aren't storing anything to the database, you don't need a ***Record** class and your part should just inherit from **ContentPart**.